# Switch from local to synced Realm

Tags: realm

I would like to use the Realm Mobile Platform to provide syncing for my app, but not force the user to register or sign in. I.e., I would like to use a local Realm at first, then switch to a synced Realm if the user decides to use that feature.

Is this possible? I couldn't find anything regarding this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to do, but you cannot automatically convert a standalone Realm into a synchronized Realm (in the future this could change). Instead, you would create a second synchronized Realm and then just copy the data from the standalone Realm into it.

As for requiring a login, currently to open a synchronized Realm you need an authorized `User` and the synced Realm URL. To get an authorized `User`, you must login with various credential mechanisms: username/password, Google, and Facebook are currently supported.

What it sounds like you need is an "anonymous" `User`, where Realm Object Server would generate an authorized `User` without a login. We plan to add this functionality in a later version and support for adding credentials to a `User`. This means that you could open a synchronized Realm immediately without a login via an "anonymous" `User` then later ask the end user to login, attaching actual credentials to the `User` object, such that if the end user used another device, they could login and identify themselves with the same underlying `User` object.