# Exception when converting local realm to synced realm in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: linq, xamarin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Be assured I have seen all the answer for the very same questions .
following this link [enter switch-from-local-to-synced-realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768828/switch-from-local-to-synced-realm)

I have a local realm from where I want to copy to synced realm .

```
    public void InitiateSyncForPost()
    {

        realm = Realm.GetInstance(ConfigForSync);

        //realm.WriteAsync((Realm obj) =>
        //{

        //    var realmOld = Realm.GetInstance(Config);
        //    var ding = realmOld.All<Post>().ToList();
        //    var dang = realmOld.All<Comment>().ToList();
        //    var ting = realmOld.All<ImageData>().ToList();
        //    foreach (var t in dang)
        //    {
        //        obj.Add(t, false);
        //    }
        //    foreach (var t in ding)
        //    {
        //        obj.Add(t, false);
        //    }
        //foreach (var t in ting)
        //    {
        //        obj.Add(t, false);
        //    }
        //});

            realm.Write(() => {
            var realmOld = Realm.GetInstance(Config);
            var ding = realmOld.All<Post>().ToList();
            var dang = realmOld.All<Comment>().ToList();
            var ting = realmOld.All<ImageData>().ToList();
      
            realmOld.Dispose();
            
            
            foreach (var t in ting)
            {
                realm.Add(t, true);
            }

            foreach (var t in dang)
            {
                realm.Add(t, true);
            }
            foreach (var t in ding)
            {
                realm.Add(t, true);
            }
             
        });

    }
```

as you can see I tried both async write and write method .
both are giving me exception

When I am using WriteAsync
I get exception something like condition not met array length == 1 (don't exactly remember )

When I am using current code I am getting this exception

*Realms.Exceptions.RealmObjectManagedByAnotherRealmException: Cannot start to manage an object with a realm when it's already managed by another realm*

Is there anything wrong I am doing in copying the object from local realm to synced realm ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create a *non-managed* copy of your `RealmObject` subsclass *before* adding it to the new Realm.

You can do this manually or via a helper extension.

#### Via `NonManagedCopy` extension from `RealmJson.Extensions`(**1**):

```
var nonSyncedRealm = Realm.GetInstance(nonSyncedRealmConfig);
var syncedRealm = Realm.GetInstance(syncedRealmConfig);

var nonSyncedAll = nonSyncedRealm.All<ARealmClass>();
syncedRealm.Write(() =>
{
    foreach (var realmObject in nonSyncedAll)
    {
        var syncedObject = realmObject.NonManagedCopy<ARealmClass>();
        syncedRealm.Add(syncedObject, true);
    }
});
```

#### Manual Copy:

Assign *each* property of your RealmObject subclass to a newly instanced non-managed object.

```
syncedRealm.Write(() =>
{
   foreach (var realmObject in nonSyncedAll)
   {
        var syncedObject = new ARealmClass
        {
            Id = realmObject.Id,
            Name = realmObject.Name,
            ~~~~~~
            ~~~~~~
            ~~~~~~
            ~~~~~~
        };
        syncedRealm.Add(syncedObject, true);
    }
});
```

(**1**) Disclaimer `RealmJson.Extensions` is an extension I wrote, available via nuget package or source:

re: https://sushihangover.github.io/Realm.Json.Extensions/

Comment: Hey Sushi ,Extremely Thankful for first answer, second answer I already wrote and was about to test , but I guess I am gonna try first one now .

Also Would you recommend writeAsync or write ? 

I guess write gonna block main UI thread or  can I run it inside Task.Run()

Comment: @saketkumar If you are on the UI thread, yes use `WriteAsync` or a `Run.Task`. I normally do all this batch-style processing on a background thread anyway, so using `Write` saves some overhead as `WriteAsync` is spinning a thread for you and in my case I do not need thread being pulled from the thread-pool, etc...

Comment: @saketkumar Which way do you end up using?

Comment: ur extension of course , :) this isn't the 1st time you rescued me ! :D

Comment: @saketkumar Thanks for the kind words! I know of a few others locally using it for Json stream loading into Realm (I use it that way a lot), but it is nice hear from others. 

Comment: I could spare a whole post about your altruistic effort to ease the path for every Xamarin developer but I know I will be reported for this bromance :D :P Thanks again !